# CORS with OData in Web.Api - modify headers in server response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors, odata

I'm running to an error of missing response headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" preflight request issue when implementing OData endpoint and trying to access from different domain. With regular api controller it is possible to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to make it work (like below). However with OData I'm struggling where such amendment to request header could be done. Is it supported with Web API?

```
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Movie movie)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        // How to sneak in sth like below to Created method or globally:  ?
        // HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, movie);
        // response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        await _service.AddMovie(movie);
        return Created(movie);
    }
```

After browsing multiple sources this is the best I found:
https://forums.asp.net/t/2032931.aspx?How+to+enable+CORS+in+Odata+NET+service+ , only this is webforms, I struggle to reapply this in Web API.

**Edit**
My statement about webforms was wrong,see below in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made use of the example I attached earlier https://forums.asp.net/t/2032931.aspx?How+to+enable+CORS+in+Odata+NET+service+ just with some modifications as below and it works fine for me to get CORS running with Odata (OData V3, Chrome, Web API 2.2). My statement about this being webforms was very wrong - it's just handling events on Application start (nicely explained in Adam Freeman's Pro MVC 5 Platform book([https://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-5-Platform/dp/1430265418](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430265418)) )

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.Request.Path.Contains("odata/"))
        {
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        }
    }
```